# Calculating number of pizzas needed and slices leftover

Tags: java

I need help figuring out how to modify my program to calculate the number of pizzas needed and then the remainder of slices. So for example if the user inputs 18 people you would need 2 pizzas (since there are 20 slices per pizza) and there would be 4 slices leftover. The slices per pizza and how many slices each person eats is constant, 2 slices per person, and 20 slices per pizza. The program asks for the amount of people attending. Also i cannot use conditional statements.

`

```
    int pizza = 20;
    int pizzaperson = 2;


    System.out.println("What is the number of people expected at the pizza party?");
    int people = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());


    int pizzatotal = (people * pizzaperson);
    int pizzaleft = pizzatotal % pizza; 
    int total = (pizza / pizzaperson) % people;
            System.out.println("For " + people + " people that would be " + pizzatotal + " pizza(s) with each person having " + pizzaperson + " slices each.");
            System.out.println("There would be " + pizzaleft + " slice(s) leftover");
```

`

Comment: Unrelated: variable names go camelCase in Java. Makes things much easier to read. And then:it is really not clear what you are asking for.

Comment: So what help do you need?  Have you tried to solve the problem yourself?  What did you try?  Have you thought about how you would do the calculation *by hand* if someone asked you?

Comment: The first suggestion I have is slightly better variable names.  In this context, it's hard to know what "pizza" is supposed to represent, for example.  A name like slicesPerPizza would go a long way towards making your code readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply find the number of pizzas required, and use that to find the number of leftover pizzas.

```
int SLICES_PER_PIZZA = 20;
int SLICES_PER_PERSON = 2;

System.out.println("What is the number of people expected at the pizza party?");
int people = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
int slices = people * SLICES_PER_PERSON;

int num_pizzas = (slices + SLICES_PER_PIZZA - 1) / SLICES_PER_PIZZA; // round up
// Alternatively, you can use Math.ceil:
// int num_pizzas = (int) Math.ceil(1.0 * slices / SLICES_PER_PIZZA); // round up
int remainder = (num_pizzas * SLICES_PER_PIZZA) - slices; 

System.out.println("For " + people + " people that would be " + num_pizzas + " pizza(s) with each person having " + SLICES_PER_PERSON + " slices each.");
System.out.println("There would be " + remainder + " slice(s) leftover");
```

Comment: Care to give a small explanation? behind the "Math.ceil" portion of code? I am not sure what exactly that is doing and this is for class. Thanks!

Comment: It's a way to round numbers up in java.
First, we need to divide the numbers of slices by the slices per pizza.
Multiplying by 1.0 makes sure that this is treated as a double, not a int.
Math.ceil rounds numbers up
(int) makes sure we can put the result into a integer.

Comment: Another question. How could i calculate this using the modulus function and not the rounding you have used?

Comment: I'll be a min, then post as another answer.

Comment: Thank you! I think my professor would probably accept that and frankly that way seems much easier than using modulus but i think that is what he wants.

Comment: Found it! posting in a min.

Comment: Actually, can't find a way to use modulus. But I have got rid of the math.ceil thing.